# Increase parallelism in Azure Functions v2

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I currently have an Azure Function v1, consuming messages from a service bus topic (through a subscription). The topic receives a large batch of messages at a predefined interval and I want the function to handle all of the messages as quickly as possible.

I'm experimenting with upgrading my function to v2. I've added a second subscription on my topic and deployed a new version of my function, targeting v2. Both functions are consuming messages from their subscription when the batch of messages are published to the topic.

I've noticed that the v2 function consumes the messages at a much slower speed than the v1 function. Since both versions of the function are executing the same code, I suspect this to be different behaviors of parallelism in v1 and v2 of Azure Functions. v1 seems to spin up more function instances to handle the messages than v2 does (I have no proof of this since I don't know how to check if this is the case).

Does anyone know if this is the case and if I can do something to increase the level of parallelism in v2? I want my function to finish the work as quickly as possible and don't really care if it needs to spin up 100 instances to do so.

Comment: Ideally they should be same, however to check the number of instances handling your requests , turn on the Application insights on function app and go to Live Metrics Stream. You can now see how many VMs are there to serve your request.

Comment: After adding AI on both functions, I now see another picture. Today, both functions are running smoothly and handling messages at pretty much the same speed. There must have been some issues yesterday. Both functions only require a single server to process the messages. This is great, but it also forced me to disable health monitor on the v2 function. If I don't do that, health monitor complaints about too many threads.

Comment: is it using consumption plan or app service plan? you can achieve high level of consumption by using consumption plans

Comment: Why using topics not queues? do you have multiple consumers other than functions?

Comment: It is using consumption plan. It think my challenge here is that while I wrote "large batch" it is not really the case. It's around 100 message, so Azure think that it is perfectly fine to just reserve one instance for this (which I guess it is). I want it to handle the messages as quickly as possible though, why it would have been nice to be able to tell it to speed up, even though there are only 100 messages.

Comment: I'm using topics, since I have multiple consumers of the messages, yes.